# Flutter Text Color Theme doesn't work under ListTile title

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting started in Flutter and just trying out stuff. 
I set a custom theme, but Text Widgets under the title property of ListTile don't get the right color. Also Icons under the leading property don't get the right color as well.

I tried setting some other colors, and sorted out, that the Problem only exists within that element.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.black,
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xff202020),
          cardTheme: CardTheme(color: Colors.black),
          textTheme: TextTheme(
              body1: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              subtitle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              headline: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white)),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() => new HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("HomePage"),
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              tooltip: "back to the last page.",
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              })
        ),
        body: Card(
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text("Test"),
            leading: new Icon(Icons.devices)
            ),
        ));
  }
}
```

The Text for the title should appear white as well as the icon, instead it is black. All other Text is white.

Comment: Use `caption` instead of `subtitle` property for `TextTheme` to change `ListTile`'s `subtitle` color.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *title* on **ListTile** is using *subhead* *textStyle* of Theme. So if you want config color of **ListTile** on **ThemeData** you need change *subhead*.

```
textTheme: TextTheme(
          subhead: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ...)
```

Comment: This works great, though Icons in the leading position are still not affected by the color change. Trying to set things like primaryIconTheme or alternateIconTheme did not fix this. Everywhere Else, Icons are getting the correct color.

Comment: If you want config theme for ListTile I suggest you use ListTileTheme wrapper for current widget or you can use Theme.of(context).color.. for color on Icon leading. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/backdrop_demo.dart

Comment: Note that the style used by a ListTile will be different depending on if its used in a drawer or not, in case of drawer it will be "theme.textTheme.bodyText1"  see the _titleTextStyle() method, currently here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/a8d820a46ec25cee9a01a72bcbb1a477f0f06ef9/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/list_tile.dart#L1049

Comment: @dangngocduc subhead is no more available in flutter 2.5.2, so I try every thing TextTheme still nothing, any idea please

Answer (score 1):

In Flutter 3 which I'm currently using, `titleMedium` defines the text style for `title` of `ListTile`s.

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    textTheme: Typography().black.copyWith(
      titleMedium: const TextStyle(
        fontSize: 32,
      ),
  ),
)
```

For example the above theme makes theme relatively large.

Flutter team should provide developers with a reference for these styles. For the moment you can find out which style corresponds to which widget by trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make use of you're theme you need to use Theme.of(context).

```
Container(
color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
child: Text(
'Text with a background color',
style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
 ),
);
```

Read more about it here in the cookbook. You are on the right track
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes

Comment: Wouldn't this mean, that I have to apply the theme to every widget individually, defeating the point of a theme ?

Comment: You still have to tell Flutter which part of the theme to use

Comment: The point in theming is  to predefine your apps color palette.  For example 
take a look at the ThemeData constructor. All of these properties can be predefined so you don't have to make color decisions on the fly. This will minimize potential design error and save you time in general. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html

Answer (score -1):

Just change body1 to bodyText1 in the following location:

> C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\charts_flutter-0.9.0\lib\src\behaviors\legend\legend_entry_layout

This will solve the issue.

Comment: IF this works, this is extremely hacky and would seemingly change every flutter project on the computer and only work for said computer. The correct solution would only require local project dart/Flutter code.